# Considerations for securly handling zip archives

Tags: zip, data-validation

I'm working with a system that allows people to upload files to be downloaded by others. At the moment, we only accept CSV files with specific columns (and we validate all data uploaded), but there is a new requirement to allow zip archives to be uploaded, and validate that all files contained in the archive meet the validation rules.

I'm conscious that quirks of the zip format can lead to subtle exploits, the [Android Master Key](https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2013-4787) exploit being one notable example.

How can I ensure that the data we have validated is the same data a recipient would see if they unzipped the archive?

Comment: Is extracting the expected CSV file(s), validating that, and compressing to a new zip file acceptable, discarding anything else?

Comment: Yes, it's acceptable, although if there is a more efficient solution that would be preferable

Comment: You don't *need* to recompress, only to access the data uncompressed. However, not doing so potentially leaves downloaders vulnerable to malicious zip files. If you are concerned about that, @Matthew's suggestion would be best.

Comment: Remember 42.zip and similar zip bombs - make sure you are accounting for that, whether by sandboxing and monitoring any extraction or by some sort of zip file analysis.